# jqGrid - Form Edit Overlay not the same as Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Pretty straight forward here for those who have used jqGrid with form editing, the jqGrid overlay to make the form edit dialog appear modal is using a '.jqmOverlay' instead of the themed '.ui-widget-overlay' for jquery.

I have attempted in afterShowForm event to remove the jqmOverlay and replace it with the ui-widget-overlay but the correct overlay (ui-widget-overlay) appears for a second before it reverts back to the incorrect (jqmOverlay).

It doesn't appear that there are any later events that happend that I could try firing off of unless I am mistaken.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
afterShowForm: function (form)
    {
        var overlayDiv = $('.jqmOverlay');
        overlayDiv.removeAttr('class');
        overlayDiv.attr('class', 'ui-widget-overlay');
        //$('.jqmOverlay').attr('class', 'ui-widget-overlay');                       

    }
```

Comment: What version of jqgrid are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) supports two different overlays: the standard `'ui-widget-overlay'` and jqModal from `jqModal.js`.

If you don't want use `jqModal` plugin you can include [jqModal:false](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) property in the list of option of Add or Edit settings. In the case the overlay will be the following:

```
<div style="display: block;" id="lui_list" class="ui-widget-overlay jqgrid-overlay"/>
```

(here war used the grid where the `<table>` element has id="list")

If you want remove the overlay you can hide it with respect of

```
afterShowForm:function(){
    $("#lui_"+grid[0].id).hide(); // hide #lui_list overlay
}
```

where `grid` is defined like `var grid=$("list");`

**UPDATED**: If you want you can hide the overlay of the grid like I described before and create your own overlay having the class 'ui-widget-overlay'. I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithEditOverlay.htm), which works in my tests without the problem which you describe. I used the following options of the Edit dialog:

```
recreateForm:true,
jqModal:false,
reloadAfterSubmit:false,
savekey: [true,13],
closeOnEscape:true,
closeAfterEdit:true,
afterShowForm:function(){
    $("#lui_"+grid[0].id).hide();
    $('body').prepend('<div class="ui-widget-overlay" id="My_list" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 949; opacity: 0.3;"/>');
},
onClose:function(){
    $('#My_list').remove();
}
```

Probably you should change the value of `opacity` or `z-index` to use it better in your application. Be careful with the setting of `z-index`. If you need increase it you can probably need to use additional value of the `zIndex` of the Edit properties.

Comment: @Oleg changing jqModal: false only applies the modal overlay to the grid and not to the page. I would prefer to have the overlay over the page like the standard jqGrid modal.

Comment: @Scruffy The Janitor: I updated my answer with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithEditOverlay.htm). You can compare it with your demo and find out where are the differences.

Comment: @Oleg: I am going to mark this as the answer, but I am really disappointed that this control does not have the option of being able to set the class or at least incorporate the theme from JQuery CSS for the full screen modal overlay.

Comment: @Scruffy: You should address your unhappiness to the developer of the jqGrid and more better post the feature request in [the trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/). I am the same user as you, I know just jqGrid better, help other jqGrid users and post many suggestions (feature requests and bug fixes)  to trirand. I know how one can change the jqGrid source code to have the corresponding support, but I can change it only in the **copy of the jqGrid code**. To be sure that the original code will be changed one should place at least the feature request.

Comment: @Oleg: I did not mean to direct my frustration at you, I do and always have appreciated your help with this control.

Comment: @Scruffy The Janitor: I understand you. In any way I find your question about the color of the overlay used by jqGrid absolutely correct. So I voted you question before I start to answer it. If you don't want to place the change request or a bug report yourself in trirand forum I could do it for you. I think that the usage of the overlay color from the jQuery UI theme (the usage of 'ui-widget-overlay' class) could be important for other users.

Comment: @Scruffy The Janitor: Some time before I posted [the bug report]. Today I have see [the fix](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/82b0d536bec52deba6101f95fbc0e56ce1467069). So in the next version of jqGrid you will not have any problem with the overlay color.